# Is it possible to call a function which takes a const rvalue as a parameter?

Tags: c++, rvalue-reference, rvalue

Recently i accidently programmed the following:

```
void someFunction(const SomeClass&& value){
    //Some Code
}
```

I didn't mean to add the 'const' keyword to the value parameter. However, this made me think: is it even possible to somehow call this function, **if an equivalent function without const exists**? If yes, does this ever make sense and is there some practical use to it?

Comment: http://www.codesynthesis.com/~boris/blog/2012/07/24/const-rvalue-references/.  "Specifically, a const rvalue will prefer to bind to the const rvalue reference rather than the const lvalue reference." But, you shouldn't bother with const rvalues. They don't make much sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct s{};     

void someFunction(s& value){ std::cout << "ref" << std::endl; }

void someFunction(const s&& value){ std::cout << "const" << std::endl; }

void someFunction(s&& value){ std::cout << "non const" << std::endl; }

const s foo() { return s(); }
s bar() { return s(); }


int main() {
    someFunction(bar());
    someFunction(foo());
    return 0;
}
```

[Prints](https://ideone.com/6o58N5)

```
non const
const
```

For some explanation (that I cannot provide ;) I refer you to [this site](http://www.codesynthesis.com/~boris/blog/2012/07/24/const-rvalue-references/). The most relevant quote is:

> [...] This makes const rvalue references pretty useless. Think about it: if
>   all we need is a non-modifiable reference to an object (rvalue or
>   lvalue), then a const lvalue reference does the job perfectly. The
>   only situation where we want to single out rvalues is if we want to
>   move them. And in that case we need a modifiable reference.

The only use case I could imagine is to use `someFunction` to detect whether a second function returns a `const` or a non-`const`, but I guess there are easier ways to find that out.

As a sidenote: When you replace `s` with `int` in above code [it prints](https://ideone.com/c4VWSN):

```
non const 
non const
```

and that is because (quoting from the same site, comment from pizer):

> There are no const prvalues of scalar types. For a const rvalue you
>   either need an Xvalue and/or a class-type object. [...]

Comment: See the comment on the linked article for more information on why with `int` it uses the non-`const` overload: *"There are no const prvalues of scalar types. For a const rvalue you either need an Xvalue and/or a class-type object. I’m almost sure that a conforming compiler would treat f(g()) just like f(1) in terms of overload resolution since g just returns a value and not an object."*

Comment: @clcto thanks for the clarification